# Best way to load game resources

Tags: android, andengine

I'm making an android game using andengine and I was wondering which is the best way to load game resources:
1) Load all resources at the beginning (during splash screen maybe)
or
2) Load a specific resource when you need it?

Comment: In my opinion, pre-load ("splash") maps and "big resources" (heavy-weight), little resources (light-weight) load when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it:

There are few resources I load in the beginning when my game starts:

1) The `Font` objects
2) The `Sound` and `Music` objects

I think loading all resources at the beginning depends on what game you got, if it has many levels and many images etc I advice you to load resources for a specific level during the 'loading' scene that will be 1-3 seconds before your level starts(For example you could create a beautiful Loading bar).

If you want a good tutorial on how to manage your scenes and your resources, I advice you to follow this link, it explains everything and it is a good base to manage your game.

[Full game tutorial(Resource and Scenes management)](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-1.html)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

use this link. which help to load dynamically all resources

[Andengine dynamically load resources](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/dynamically-load-all-textures-texture-regions-t4139.html)